# How do I solve differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+5x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+5x$

I don't understand what type of differential equation is this. What to do with 't', we don't have it on right side at all?

Comment: Type: *separable*.

Comment: Did (above) always hits the nail on the head...I sometimes embed that nail i.e. The equation is separable: $$\frac {dx}{x^2+5x} = dt \iff \frac {dx}{x(x+5)}= dt$$ Now use partial fractions.

Comment: One possible source of confusion is that you may be more familiar with $x$ as the *independent* variable, with $y$ (say) a function of $x$.  Here it is the *dependent* variable: $x$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: What you said isn't true. The notation on the left side implies that $x$ is really a function of $t$. So you could write the DE as $$\frac d{dt}x(t) = (x(t))^2 + 5\cdot x(t)$$

Comment: @MPW: Who is that directed at?

Comment: @briantung : It was a comment on the original post, not you

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{dx}{x(x+5)}=dt$$
$$\frac{dx}{5x}-\frac{dx}{5(x+1)}=dt$$

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $5x$ from both sides to get it into the form of a [Bernoulli Differential Equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx). From there, you have to make a substitution, and then you can solve it like a first order differential equation. To answer the problem with the lack of a $t$ in the differential equation, your $f(t)=1$.

As pointed out in the comments, you could also solve it as a [Separable Differential Equation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Separable.aspx), in which you get all your $x$'s on one side and all your $t$'s on another side. Either way, your $f(t)=1$.